# How to personalize Scopes in Ubuntu Mobile at Aquaris M10 tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, scopes, m10

There are these pre-configured home screens called *Scopes* on the BQ M10 Ubuntu Edition tablet. After some [research](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2873192/opensource-subnet/what-the-heck-are-ubuntu-unitys-scopes.html) I've finally got an idea what scopes are meant for.

With understanding the concept of Scopes, the desire to adjust these Scopes to one's own needs arises. However, I can't figure out how to actually customize a Scope's content. Lets consider the News Scope. When opening the settings dialogue, a list of international news resources is displayed. All content resources are activated by default. All I can 'configure' here is to check or uncheck the defaults. However, living neither in an English nor Spanish speaking region, I'd rather *add* my own news resources to that scope.

How to do this?

The Location Scope appears as useless to me, too. Again, how to include customized content sources in there? Are Scopes actually *meant* to be customized?

Answer (score 0):

With one of the scopes open, swipe up from the bottom of the screen. You'll see the list of scopes starting with the enabled ones. Click on the star on the right to toggle whether a scope shows or not.

The sources contributing to each scope can also be changed with the settings button you found. If the source you're interested in is not available perhaps you could use the RSS scope?

More scopes may be found in the Ubuntu store but the selection is not exhaustive (yet)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Tim. The possibilities you described are the ones I've already checked, too. However, as you wrote, all I can actually 'configure' is to toggle either the scope or its default data sources on or off. However, I'd rather wish to include custom data sources in a specific scope. Maybe I should have a look at an RSS scope. But what's the point of a scope just reading RSS feeds as any arbitrary RSS reader...?